# How to count word frequency in a set of documents using node.js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a set of documents in MongoDB.

[image]

In NodeJS with [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), I'd like to count the number of occurrences of each word.
The result should be something like:

```
[
    "latest": 2,
    "sprint": 2,
    "lair": 1,
    "laugh": 1,
    "fault": 1,
    "lemma": 2,
    "on": 1,
]
```

Any idea how to do this with MongoDB aggregation framework?

I read that [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/aggregation-introduction/) has better performance since aggregation runs natively in the server (C++), whereas mapReduce spawns separate javascript thread(s) to run JavaScript code.
But I'm starting with MongoDB and I haven't found a way to do it with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used Mongo but hopefully this helps:

```
db.TestDocuments.aggregate([

  // Unwind each element of the array into its own document
  { $unwind: "$words" },

  // Group and count the total of each occurrence for each word
  { $group: { 
    _id: "$words" , 
    count: { "$sum": 1 }
  }},

  // Remove the id field from the response, rename it to the word
  { $project: { "_id": 0, "word": "$_id", "count": 1 } },

  // Sort the results with highest occurrences first
  { $sort: { "count": -1 } }
]);
```

Results in this structure:

```
{ "count" : 2, "word" : "latest" }
{ "count" : 2, "word" : "sprint" }
{ "count" : 2, "word" : "lemma" }
{ "count" : 1, "word" : "lair" }
{ "count" : 1, "word" : "laugh" }
{ "count" : 1, "word" : "fault" }
{ "count" : 1, "word" : "on" }
```

Comment: That's quite correct.  Thank you for your help.

I set `{ $out: "TermFrequency" }`  to takes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes them to a `TermFrequency` collection.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to calculate the IDF (Inverse Document Frequency) in the same way?